Group data differently in bar chart
I am trying to build a bar-graph using chart.js where i add "random" groups of data. Each group should be labeled with a group name and each bar with the property it really represents.
Data is fetched from a DB and the groups may differ in size, depending on the selection criteria of the user.
In Excel it is possible to achieve a result similar to the desired one (padding each new dataset with 0 for each already existing bar). The drawback is that with each new dataset the bars grow thinner and thinner.

A similar result is achievable with Chart.js using the same trick. Each new dataset is padded with null so the bars don't get mixed up with the previous ones. By setting skipNull: true the bars don't grow thinner.
So far so good, but when you click on a category name in the legend, its data is hidden, but the labels on X-Axis and the gaps left by the hidden bars still remain. It would be very useful to hide/show some of the added categories to enable a closer comparison between two categories.
In a previous SO-Question, the only answer tells it is not possible to achieve my desired result, but this QA is seven years old, so things might have changed.
Another SO-Post achieves a similar result by reordering the data and putting the Bar-Names as labels on top of the bars, but it loses the ability to hide a category. (The legend is hidden to avoid it, if you show the legend and click on one item, it will not hide a category but the n-th element of all categories. Try it out on the demo of the accepted answer, edit line 76)
An alternative approach would be to add a separate "chart-object" to the same canvas sharing the axes, is there any possibility to achieve this?

Your post is missing a [mre], so we don't know what have you done (wrong); for instance, we don't know why your bars are shrinking so much. They shouldn't see fiddle if nulls are always kept in sync, as they should. Also, it's not clear what exactly you intend to achieve; for instance you link to a post about tooltip content, but don't tell what needs to be changed in your tooltip. Changing the x-axis when a group is hidden through the legend is an interesting and achievable proposition, see fiddle.

Thanks @kikon for the fiddles (and shame on me for not writing them, a mix of lazy and don't know where to begin).
Anyway: your second fiddle is exactly what i was looking for: a bar graph with grouped data AND the possibility to hide/show the groups. I was missing the possibility to define a callback on legend.onClick.
Would you mind to put your code or the fiddle as an answer?

The bars shouldn't shrink if skipNull option is set true and one adds nulls for the datasets that don't have data at certain x positions; if each dataset is to have an exclusive, contiguous
region of the x axis, then its data should have nulls for all positions of the regions allocated to other datasets. Those nulls should be kept in sync whenever new data is added. Here's a snippet implementing those ideas, and also adds an empty x category to separate consecutive datasets:


const config = {
    type: "bar",

    data: {
        labels: ['Cox-Orange', 'GS', 'Golden', 'Redlove'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Apples',
                data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()),
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            },
        ]
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        barPercentage: 0.99,
        categoryPercentage: 0.95,
        skipNull: true,
        scales:{
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function addDataGroup(newGroupLabel, newAxisLabels, newData, color){
    const nNew = newAxisLabels.length,
        datasets = chart.data.datasets,
        nExisting = datasets[datasets.length-1].data.length;
    for(const dataset of datasets){
        dataset.data.push(...Array(nNew + 1).fill(null));
    }
    const newDataset = {
        label: newGroupLabel,
        data: Array(nExisting+1).fill(null).concat(newData),
        backgroundColor: color
    }
    datasets.push(newDataset);
    chart.data.labels.push('', ...newAxisLabels);
    chart.update();
}

const chart = new Chart('myChart', config);
setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup('Citrus', ['Oranges', 'Lemon', 'Pomelo', 'Tangerine'],
            Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'orange');
    }, 2000
);

setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup('Cucumber', ['Straight', 'Curved', 'Long'],
            Array.from({length: 3}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'green');
    }, 5000
);

setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup('Exotic', ['Pomelo', 'Papaya', 'Pineapple', 'Banana'],
            Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'yellow');
    }, 8000
);
<div style="height: 300px">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



or as jsFiddle.
As for the x axis adapting to datasets being hidden through the legend, by eliminating the
categories that no longer have visible data, that is an interesting proposition. It can be
implemented through legend.onClick and then manipulating the chart.data.labels. One has to also adjust the datasets themselves in order to keep the nulls mentioned above in sync with the labels - remove the nulls for a dataset that was just hidden and add them back when the dataset is made visible again:


const config = {
    type: "bar",

    data: {
        labels: ['Cox-Orange', 'GS', 'Golden', 'Redlove'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Apples',
                data: Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()),
                backgroundColor: 'red'
            },
        ]
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        barPercentage: 0.99,
        categoryPercentage: 0.95,
        skipNull: true,
        scales:{
            x: {
                ticks: {
                    minRotation: 90
                }
            }
        },
        plugins:{
            legend:{
                labels: {
                    color: 'black'
                },
                onClick: toggleGroupWithLabels
            }
        }
    }
};

const unhiddenData = {data:[], labels:[]};
// can be linked to the chart object if global variables are inconvenient

function initUpdates(chart){
    if(unhiddenData.data.length === 0){
        if(chart.data.datasets.length > 1){
            throw new Error('Cannot start with multiple datasets');
        }
        else if(chart.data.datasets.length === 1){
            unhiddenData.data.push([...chart.data.datasets[0].data]);
            unhiddenData.labels = [[...chart.data.labels]];
        }

    }
}

function addDataGroup(chart, newGroupLabel, newAxisLabels, newData, color){
    chart.options.plugins.legend.onClick = () => null; // disable legend toggle while updating
    chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.color = 'lightgray'; // visual indication for above
    chart.options.animation.onComplete = () => {
        chart.options.plugins.legend.onClick = toggleGroupWithLabels;
        chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.color = 'black';
        setTimeout(()=>chart.update('none'), 0);
    }

    chart.data.datasets.push({label: newGroupLabel, backgroundColor: color, data: []})

    unhiddenData.data.push(newData)
    unhiddenData.labels.push(newAxisLabels);

    _updateData(chart);

    chart.update();
}

function _updateData(chart){
    const nDatasets = chart.data.datasets.length,
        hidden = Array.from({length: nDatasets}, (_, i)=>chart.getDatasetMeta(i).hidden);
    if(hidden.length < nDatasets){
        hidden.push(true);
    }
    chart.data.labels = [];
    const labels = chart.data.labels;
    for(let i = 0; i < nDatasets; i++){
        if(!hidden[i]){
            if(labels.length > 0){
                labels.push('');
            }
            labels.push(...unhiddenData.labels[i]);
        }
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < nDatasets; i++){
        if(!hidden[i]){
            chart.data.datasets[i].data = [];
            const data = chart.data.datasets[i].data;
            for(let j = 0; j < nDatasets; j++){
                if(!hidden[j]){
                    if(data.length > 0){
                        data.push(null);
                    }
                    if(i === j){
                        data.push(...unhiddenData.data[j])
                    }
                    else{
                        data.push(...unhiddenData.data[j].map(() => null));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function toggleGroupWithLabels(...args){
    const {chart} = args[0],
        {datasetIndex} = args[1];
    const metaToggle = chart.getDatasetMeta(datasetIndex);
    metaToggle.hidden = !metaToggle.hidden;


    _updateData(chart);
    chart.update('none');
}

const chart = new Chart('myChart', config);
initUpdates(chart)

setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup(chart, 'Citrus', ['Oranges', 'Lemon', 'Pomelo', 'Tangerine'],
            Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'orange');
    }, 3000
);

setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup(chart, 'Cucumber', ['Straight', 'Curved', 'Long'],
            Array.from({length: 3}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'green');
    }, 6000
);

setTimeout(
    ()=>{
        addDataGroup(chart, 'Exotic', ['Pomelo', 'Papaya', 'Pineapple', 'Banana'],
            Array.from({length: 4}, () => 100 + 200 * Math.random()), 'yellow');
    }, 9000
)
<div style="height: 300px">
    <canvas id="myChart">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>



or as jsFiddle.
